# Angular 2 + I have an external plugin in angular 2 and it doesn't work but when I reload the whole page it will work perfectly

Tags: javascript, plugins, angular, jquery-plugins, external

Angular 2 + I have an external plugin in angular 2 and it doesn't work but when I reload the whole page it will work perfectly.. My question is how can I implement my external plugin without reloading my whole page?

I include these in my index.html

assets/js/plugins/responsive-tabs.js  and
assets/js/components/tabs.js

and this is the code that I want to implement

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-plugin="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineOne" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineOne"
        role="tab" aria-expanded="true">Contact Information</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" style="display: block;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineTwo" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineTwo"
        role="tab">General Information</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" style="display: block;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineThree" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineThree"
        role="tab">Account Representatives</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" style="display: block;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineFour" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineFour"
        role="tab">Vendor Representatives</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown" role="presentation" style="display: none;">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="caret"></span>&nbsp;Other Details</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li class="" role="presentation" style="display: none;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineOne" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineOne"
            role="tab" aria-expanded="false">Contact Information</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="" style="display: none;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineTwo" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineTwo"
            role="tab" aria-expanded="false">General Information</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineThree" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineThree"
            role="tab" aria-expanded="false">Account Representatives</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineFour" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineFour"
            role="tab">Vendor Representatives</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineFive" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineFive"
            role="tab">Description</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exampleTabsLineSix" aria-controls="exampleTabsLineSix"
            role="tab">Routing Notes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-tabs-autoline" style="transition-duration: 0.5s, 1s; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1); left: 0px; width: 81px;"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Show your code, including how you use the plugin.

Comment: Thanks to your feedback please see the above update Thanks